# Vim with terminal inside, I have to quit using a vim cmd as the terminal will prevent me from exiting, so I can't do :wq

Tags: vimrc, terminal

Since I have a terminal inside vim I can't do `:wq` or I get 'job' running.

I got around this using:

`vim --clean "+term" "+qa!"`

Then I'd have to do `:w` then `:qa!`

In my `~/.vimrc` I then done this map:

`command Q qa!`

So now I do `:w` then `:Q`

I'd like to do: `:wq` or at least have a map for it.

I tried mapping: `command Q wqa!` but got 'job running'; I couldn't exit because of the terminal.

It's not possible to do `vim --clean "+term" "+wqa!`

#### Question

Is there a way I can exit vim with terminal inside using `:wq` or a map of it?

It's a minor inconvenience to do `:w` then `:Q`, help is appreciated.

Comment: Some helpful ideas: `:help E947`, `:help :term` and look at `++kill` and the last few paragraphs between `:help :term` and `:help terminal-close`, `:help terminal-typing` and use C-w C-\ (which usually sends sigquit)

Comment: thank you, could you write an answer so I cam give credit? I'll try this.

Comment: Tried to do `:term_setkill={SIGKILL}` but I get 'executing job failed: no such file or directory'

Comment: `:term_setkill()={SIGKILL}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what I wanted by doing:

```
:w|:Q
```

For context Q is a command in my ~/.vimrc:

`command Q qa!`

---

All the steps to write and exit vim with terminal inside:

On terminal:

```
vim --clean "+term" "+qa!"
```

In ~/.vimrc:

```
command Wq w|qa!
```

Then you can write and exit vim with terminal running inside:

`:Wq`

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
function! CorrectCmd()
  if getcmdtype() != ':'
    echo 'foo'
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  if matchstr(getcmdline(), '^wq\%[all]!\?\>') == ''
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  return "\<C-u>" . 'w|qa' . "\<CR>"
endfunction
cnoremap <expr> <CR> CorrectCmd()
```

The command mapping map <kbd>Enter</kbd> in command mode.

If the command match `wq` or something equivalent (e.g.: `wqall`) it translate it into `w|qa` otherwise it keep it as it is before executing it.

Comment: `echo 'foo'`: debugging?